# Ubuntu 17.10 poor memory management, system hangs

Tags: 17.10, lenovo

I am using Lenovo Legion Y520 with Ubuntu 17.10,

Since upgrading from 16.04 to 17.10, I am noticing very poor memory management on 17.10. The system hangs when using Firefox with multiple tabs, and the only solution is to press the power button to restart the computer if it is hanging.

Lenovo Legion Y520 have 8GB RAM + Core i7 7th gen laptop with OS installed on 128GB SSD, but still it's facing a hanging issue. I'm not sure how to fix this.

Firefox version 59.0.2 (64-bit) - I don't really know if Firefox causing this issue, but the system is hanging.

Comment: I would first determine what version of Firefox you have and then follow standard troubleshooting procedures for running Firefox in Ubuntu--many people have had the same problem. For example try running in Safe Mode to see if a plugin or extension is possibly causing issues. Other guides suggest disabling graphics hardware acceleration and OpenGL. if other programs are causing problems for you, please include those in your question.

Comment: I think this is a kernel bug with the swapping/memory code. From kernel 4.11(?) something changed.  See:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1472336

Comment: See also :
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/159356